# creating entitites as inheritance class from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, software-design, clean-architecture

I am working on a project where I have multiple entities (class/objects). The code is written in Python and in general the data is read in to a `pandas.DataFrame` through different gateways.

All the entities inherit from the `pandas.DataFrame`. They just have the name of an entity (example Car), but they are a `pandas.DataFrame`.

```
import pandas

class Car(pandas.DataFrame):
   def __init__(self, *args,**kargs):
      pandas.DataFrame.__init__(self,*args,**kargs)
```

My problem is that I actually can't see from the code, what the attributes/variables of the classes/entities are. And I am thinking about how it would affect the performance, if I pass all the columns from a `DataFrame` to the class and use member variables and add a `toDataFrame` method to every entity, so I can transform it back to a `DataFrame` when necessary.

The output of my use-case is a JSON. And the different dataframes are accessed column by column on different places in the code.

Is it a good practice to use such a class as an entity?

Would it be better to convert the dataframe according to an entity into a real class entity with variables?

Comment: I guess inheriting all behavior from `pandas.DataFrame` is an overhead. Just use dataframe as internal structure

Comment: and your recommendation would be to remove the entities?

Comment: This is a recurrent question for me. Did you find any answer in other forum?

Comment: no i have no answer